# matches enum и массива строк

Tags: java, enum

```
     if(strArr[0].matches("тест")) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
```

Хочу матчить первый элемент массива строк и первую константу списка enum (вместо слова "тест").
А в список занесу запрещенные слова.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

#### Вот написал много полезных функций:

Функция которую требует Ваш вопрос - `matches`

---

Инфо о других функциях:
`hasString(параметр 1,параметр 2)` - проверяет есть ли в строке-`параметр 1` элемент №`параметр 2`

`checkAll(параметр 1)` - проверяет есть ли в строке-`параметр 1` хотя бы один елемент из **enum**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Проверка matches
        System.out.println(matches("тест", 0));
        System.out.println(matches("T0", 0));
        
        // Проверка прочих функций:
        // hasString - проверяет есть ли в строке<параметр 1> элемент №<параметр 2>
        System.out.println(hasString("To T", 0));
        System.out.println(hasString("To T0", 0));
        System.out.println(hasString("To T0", 1));
        // checkAll - проверяет есть ли в строке<параметр 1> хотя бы один елемент из enum
        System.out.println(checkAll("Test - T0"));
        System.out.println(checkAll("Test - T4"));
        System.out.println(checkAll("Test - T"));
    }
    private static boolean checkAll(String str) {
        ArrayList<Test> arr = getList();
        for (Test test : arr) 
            if(-1 != str.indexOf(test.toString()))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    private static boolean hasString(String str, int id) {
        return -1 != str.indexOf(getElement(id));
    }
    
    public static boolean matches(String str, int id) {
        return getElement(id).equals(str);
    }
    
    public static String getElement(int id) {
        return getList().get(id).toString();
    }
    
    private static ArrayList<Test> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Test>(Arrays.asList(Test.values()));
    }

    public enum Test {
        TEST0 ("T0"),
        TEST1 ("T1"),
        TEST2 ("T2"),
        TEST3 ("T3"),
        TEST4 ("T4");

        private String string;
        
        Test(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }       

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return string;
        }
    }
```